# Launching URLs from Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, browser, start-menu, file-association

I am on a Windows 10 machine here, and entering an URL into the start menu search will only give me the option to open that website with edge, even though a different default browser is installed. If I run

```
explorer http://www.google.com/
```

from the command line, the website opens in my default browser, which is not edge. However, if I press the start button and type `http://www.google.com`, `Enter`, it will open the website in edge.

**Question:** (How) can I setup Windows such that entering a URL into the start menu search will open it with my default browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be some inconsistency of the Windows 10 Start Menu.

Until it is fixed by Microsoft, you could instead use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
to enter the URL, since this will honor your default browser setting.

Otherwise, if you are looking for a better Start Menu, I recommend the free
[Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/).

Comment: I could never really settle on using 3rd party software for the start menu. This was the final nail though, I installed Classic Shell as you suggested and it works great. Solves other annoying problems as well. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up to this, I have now bought 2 licenses for https://www.startisback.com/, I am very happy with it.